# Subir a WordPress un proyecto Django

Tags: python, django, wordpress

Querría saber cómo se podría implementar en mi sitio WordPress (dominio y host, no es en local) un proyecto Django el cual ejecuta un bot que automatiza funciones mediante selenium en las redes sociales.

En local el bot funciona perfectamente: ejecuto el servidor desde la consola de VS, busco la página HTML que tengo configurada en el archivo `urls.py`, relleno el formulario que aparece en el HTML, le doy a enviar y lanza el archivo `bot.py` que es el que tiene la herramienta en sí.

Quiero subir el proyecto tal cual a WordPress si es posible. Si no fuese posible, ¿habría alguna manera de lanzar el archivo `bot.py` desde un formulario de WordPress? Prescindiendo, en este caso, de Django.

También se me había ocurrido hacer del bot una aplicación de escritorio mediante la librería tkinter y una vez hecha, subirla a WordPress para que se ejecute desde ahí. Tampoco he encontrado mucha información sobre esto.

He buscado mucha información durante días, que si haciendo una REST API, creando un Plugin mediante PHP e instalándolo en WordPress, usando la librería django-wordpress-api (no sirve exactamente para lo que quiero)... pero no doy con ello.

No pongo código porque realmente no se si es necesario, ya que mis dudas no están ahí.

Comment: Mmm... puedes hacerlo, pero necesitas tener python instalado en tu servidor.

Comment: Hola @Christian , y cómo lo haría una vez instalado python en el server? gracias por comentar.

Comment: En principio si en local funciona, repitiendo los pasos en el servidor debería funcionar, eso sí como indica @Christian debes permitir ejecutar Python en el servidor, luego debes ir a la URL en la que está tu archivo .py y ejecutarlo en el navegador, para integrarlo con WP o automatizarlo deberías hacer un replanteamiento de tu APP.

Comment: Más o menos conseguí hacerlo con una app Heroku. Ahora tengo el problema de que la petición es muy larga y el router de heroku solo está activo 30 segundos...